# how do I stop invisible elements from being triggered when "overlay" div is not active

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I'm using flexbox to align the items inside the overlay div, everything is working fine how it's supposed to except the anchor tags that are being triggered without even having to open the menu and the tags are invisible but clickable just beside the menu, how do I fix it without having to change the style of the menu or overlay? Any help is appreciated. Cheers!

```js
$(function() {

  $(".menu-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".menu-overlay").toggleClass("open");
    $(".menu").toggleClass("open");

  });

});

$('.menu-link').click(function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
});
```

```css
.nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 5%;
}

#brandname {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Circular Std Black;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
  right: 5%;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
}

.menu-link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1002;
}

.menu-icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-line {
  background-color: white;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-line-2 {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.menu-line-3 {
  bottom: 0;
}
.menu.open .menu-line-1 {
  transform: translateY(7.5px) translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu.open .menu-line-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu.open .menu-line-3 {
  transform: translateY(-7.5px) translateY(50%) rotate(45deg);
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-circle {
  background-color: #E095F0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu:hover .menu-circle {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.menu.open .menu-circle {
  transform: scale(60);
}

/* ------------- */
.menu-overlay {
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity:0;
  display:block;
}

.menu-overlay.open {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1001;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in-out;
}


.no-scroll{
    overflow: hidden;
}



.contents {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.contents a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Circular Std Book;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;

}

.contents a:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <div id="brandname">Test</div>
    <div class="menu">
      <span class="menu-circle"></span>
      <a href="#" class="menu-link">
        <span class="menu-icon">
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-1"></span>
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-2"></span>
          <span class="menu-line menu-line-3"></span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-overlay">
        <div class="contents">
              <a href="{% url 'main:homepage' %}">Home</a>
              <a href="{% url 'main:login' %}">Log in</a>
              <a href="{% url 'main:signup' %}">Sign up</a>
              <a href="#">About</a>
        </div>
    </div>


</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using `pointer-events` to stop mouse events
https://jsfiddle.net/vghszb1n/

```
.contents a {
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;

  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Circular Std Book;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

.open .contents a {
  cursor: pointer !important;
  pointer-events: all !important;
}
```